# Toggle javascript debug in Django template

Tags: javascript, django, debugging

I am working on the javascript side of a Django project and my javascript functions output some text to the console so that I can debug more easily. My javascript files look like the following:

```
(function(nameSpace, $, undefined ) {
    var debug = true;

    nameSpace.foo = function() {
        if (debug) {
            console.log('foo was there')
        }
    };

}(window.nameSpace = window.nameSpace || {}, jQuery ));
```

I thought that it would be preferable to toggle off this output in production but I don't want to change each javascript file. So I thought I would create a `context_processor` to pass the value of `settings.DEBUG` to my base template.

Now I have in my base.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <script> var window.debug = {{ DEBUG }}; </script>
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

and my javascript files have `var debug = window.debug` instead of a hardcoded boolean.

Looking back into this I am wondering if this is safe. I presume someone could easily temper with the `window.debug` variable, which is fine as long as the console output doesn't leak security information like `csrf` tokens for example. I am not a security expert but I feel something a bit slippery here.

Is my current idea safe? And if not how could I toggle javascript debug more securely for the whole project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current idea is safe, if a bit awkward and perhaps sloppy.  Leaking CSRF tokens or other to the console is not a problem per se, as the only way to access the console history programmatically would be to have saved it prior to executing `console.log` and family  (or to have already received malicious JS on your page -- at which point you're hosed anyway).  The inability to copy from the console is enforced by the browser as it would otherwise be a huge attack vector (en masse, we coders are *sloppy*!).

An alternative, perhaps cleaner option to a client-side debug variable might be to co-opt the console.* functions entirely.  Consider:

```
{% if not DEBUG %}
<script>
    window.console = (function(){
        var c = {}; c.log = c.warn = c.debug = c.info = c.error = c.time = c.dir = c.profile = c.clear = c.exception = c.trace = c.assert = function(s){};
        return c;
    })();
</script>
{% endif %}
```

In other words, just leave the `console.log()` calls there outright.  Meanwhile, in the DEBUG case, omit the above entirely and voila, the debugging information is available.

Note that this is no less sloppy, as "doing it right" would mean not having those instrumentation calls there at all in the non DEBUG case, but just removes the need for the extra JS hoopla at all the call sites.  Meanwhile, the JIT will intelligently remove all those function calls entirely (as they're now NOOPs) and you get a mild performance boost to boot.

Comment: Thanks for a nice answer. I appreciate both content and style.